# Changing time limits in PHP to lower

Tags: php

I have a project, running PHP, with regular AJAX post requests (every 60 seconds). Unfortunately, the server keep reaching it's resource limits (I'm on shared hosting), namely - CPU %.

I tried almost everything, and finally I come to the idea of decreasing set_time_limit in PHP. Can someone tell if there will be any difference in this? Will this make the scripts "release" their resources quicker? Or on the contrary - this will either have no effect, or the effect will be negative?

Thanks in advance for all the answers!

P.S. I'm trying to decrease the time with:

```
set_time_limit(5);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 5);
```

The PHP is running on FastCGI.

Comment: If you need to set a time limit on your requests to 5 seconds then you should rather fix whatever is taking more than 5 seconds (**especially** if you run it once every minute).

Comment: php release resources when the script ends. You can "cache" stuff like database selects to better performance.

Comment: Sounds OK, but can't find what it is it. When I'm watching the logs, the MySQL isn't the problem. The JS AJAX returns a very small amount of data, the template files are separated, small ones... I'm stuck, this is one of the last decisions.

Comment: @ZiTAL - I'm using memcache, but before and after using it - the problem stays.

Comment: every time you call `set_time_limit()`, you're resetting the clock. If you had run for 4.9999 seconds when s_t_l(5) is called, you'll get another 5 seconds of runtime, allowing you to go up to 9.999 seconds total.

Comment: @MarcB: time_limit is called just once, at the begin of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're hitting max CPU for prolonged periods of time **that** is the issue you need to address; not killing the processes prematurely.

If you're posting regular CPU intensive ajax requests try the following;

- On the server-side, see if you can make 'shortcuts' to crunching data. If nothings been modified or needs to be modified, have the script cut as early as possible. E.g. check the modification time on your data, and add 'not modified' functionality to your script and request handling.
- Optimise your script. Use "callgrinding" to identify problem areas.
- Make sure you aren't looping mysql queries; try to run fewer queries and have any loops just assemble larger queries (such as inserts)
- See if the ajax requests need to be made on those intervals. For example, using Javascript attempt to detect if the user is looking at the screen (e.g. the window is unfocused); stop doing requests while the user is away or space requests much more sparsely.
- Put your ajax requests into two queues based on activity. If the user was recently active (moved the mouse, focused the window) switch to 1-minute intervals. If it's been a while, space the intervals further apart so you aren't doing so many queries.

**The solution should NOT be killing scripts earlier or causing crashes intentionally**. That's opening the door to very unwelcome problems. If you're using ajax to frequently ping a service, those calls need to be short and fast.

Comment: MySQL is not the problem - there are total of 10 queries, with less than 0.006 sec  execution time. The script generates amount of arrays, and it has all this "switch-on", "switch-off" stuff - I deliver only the events pas the last recorded time... I'm really stuck at this. What is "callgrinding"?

Comment: Callgrinding is using something called 'Xdebug', if you google 'webgrind' you'll get the info. What it does is profiles your PHP script, and gives you statistics on your script (what functions were called, how often, where, how much time they took, how many calculations things took). It even gives you a nice graph showing the 'heat' areas of your script are generating. The queries don't sound like a problem, callgrinding will probably be the key to finding the bottlenecks. When I first started callgrinding I improved performance by magnitudes in only a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

If a PHP program runs longer than the max execution time, it will crash with a timeout error.

Simply changing your max execution time won't make anything run faster; but if your code is taking longer than 5 seconds to run, then it will cause your program to crash instead of finishing.

This will certainly free up server resources, but probably not in a way that's useful.

If you've got programs that are taking a long time to run (ie anything more than a second for this kind of program), your best option is to do some performance analysis on the program itself; use a tool like XDebug to analyse where the bottlenecks are and why it's going slowly, and improve the program to make it quicker.